# C# SQLite Update error (SQL Logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error.”)

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a WPF application with various textboxes and a dropdown box. I am trying to update my SQLite db, with the details that are entered into them. I have re-worked the method before I used to insert the data into the SQLite db in the first place. The issue is when I execute the code I get an error “SQL Logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error.”

```
private void ButtonEditExmUpdate_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    {
        var ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;

        using (var DbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnString))
        {
            try
            {var InsertIntoTable = (@"Update [Exm]
                Set(ExmID = @ExmID, ExmEnvironmentType = @ExmEnvironmentType, ExmURL = @ExmURL, ExmServer = @ExmServer, ExmModifiedDate = @ExmModifiedDate, ExmDeleted = @ExmDeleted)
                WHERE(Exm.ExmDeleted = 0) AND (Exm.ExmID = '" + ExmID.Text + "')");
                var insertIntoUsernamePasswordString = (@"Update [ExmUsernamePassword]
                Set (ExmUsername = @ExmUsername, ExmPassword = @ExmPassword,  ExmServer = @ExmServer, ExmModifiedDate = @ExmModifiedDate)
                WHERE(ExmUsernamePassword.Deleted = 0) AND (ExmUsernamePassword.ExmUsernamePasswordsID = '" + ExmUsernamePasswordsID.Text + "')");
                var insertIntoExmTable = new SQLiteCommand(insertIntoExmTableString);
                var insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable = new SQLiteCommand(insertIntoUsernamePasswordString);

                insertIntoExmTable.Connection = DbConnection;
                insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable.Connection = DbConnection;
                DbConnection.Open();

                insertIntoExmTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmEnvironmentType", ComboBoxExmEnvironmentType.Text);
                insertIntoExmTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmURL", TextBoxExmUrl.Text);
                insertIntoExmTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmServer", TextBoxExmServerName.Text);
                insertIntoExmTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmModifiedDate", ModifiedDateTime);

                insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmUsername", TextBoxExmUsername.Text);
                insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmPassword", TextBoxExmPassword.Text);
                insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmServer", TextBoxExmServerName.Text);
                insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExmModifiedDate", ModifiedDateTime);

                try
                {
                    insertIntoExmTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DbConnection.Close();
                    DbConnection.Open();
                    insertIntoExmUsernamePasswordTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DbConnection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error:
SQL Logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and `missing database` suggests that you didn't set a default db when you connected to sqlite, so either you need `update dbname.table ...`, or select the appropriate db before running the queries.

Comment: ExmPassword and ExmServer are double, copy paste error ?

Comment: @x... Yes that was a copy and paste error have now updated.

Comment: @MarcB Okay I understand that but this will be an individual application and not to worried about that at the moment. In terms of missing database, I am call that from the configuration manager (Var ConnString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what was causing the issue, this was because my SET statements were within brackets, so the final code looks like this for the SQL strings.

```
var InsertIntoTable = (@"Update [Exm]
                Set ExmID = @ExmID, ExmEnvironmentType = @ExmEnvironmentType, ExmURL = @ExmURL, ExmServer = @ExmServer, ExmModifiedDate = @ExmModifiedDate, ExmDeleted = @ExmDeleted 
                WHERE(Exm.ExmDeleted = 0) AND (Exm.ExmID = '" + ExmID.Text + "')");
var insertIntoUsernamePasswordString = (@"Update [ExmUsernamePassword]
                Set ExmUsername = @ExmUsername, ExmPassword = @ExmPassword,  ExmServer = @ExmServer, ExmModifiedDate = @ExmModifiedDate
                WHERE(ExmUsernamePassword.Deleted = 0) AND (ExmUsernamePassword.ExmUsernamePasswordsID = '" + ExmUsernamePasswordsID.Text + "')");
```